# Cannot get plots to show in a jupyter notebook using %matplotlib inline and plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am trying to simply copy a code from the following link:

http://rajeshrinet.github.io/blog/2014/ising-model/

It is the first block of code that produces the 4 subplots. It already has the lines %matplotlib inline and plt.show() which are the normal reasons that plots won't show up. Also, no errors are produced to guide me in what is going wrong. Does anyone see what the problem is? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you wait until the code run completed? I tried the same code and it takes quite some time to run.

Comment: Thank you so much!